# Can I use 2 or more Layouts in 1 Activity?

Tags: java, android

I have ca. **30 Buttons** in an Activity (layout.xml (here are the buttons), `mainActivity.java` (here is the code).

**So, my question is:** Can I use 30 different layout, for that 1 activity, or I have to make 30 different activity? I'd like to put all layout 2 gifs, and therefor I don't know how can I do this. Which option is the best, and if the first, how can I import to the layout or activity the gifs? 
Thanks for the answers! (Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achive. Please paste your layout and Activity code. 



Tip: To attach layouts to activity you can use `LayoutInflater` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: I have one button. To this button I have to make a new layout, that's include 2 gifs, But I don't know how can i do this. (The button has to open the new layout, that's have the 2 gifs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will including multiple layouts help like below ?

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

     <include
            layout="@layout/layout_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/layout_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make for example a activity,  GifActivity

And when you click on the button send your gif path to your GifActivity so you have one activity with one layout.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GifActivity.class);   
i.putExtra("GIF_PATH", hereTHePathToYourGif);
StartActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one main layout and then include two layout in main layout by using include tag